# c# Accessing Creation Class Variables From Instance

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, instance

Just a basic programming question.

```
public class ClassA
{
    int i = 10;
    void Start()
    {
        ClassB b = new ClassB(this);
        b.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    ClassA a;
    public ClassB(ClassA a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.i);
    }
}
```

I would really like to omit the a:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.i);
->
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

What is the most reasonable method of achieving this?

(Note: ClassB must not inherit from ClassA, as ClassA inherits from something ClassB cannot. And I suppose I should say I don't want to pass parameters to the functions, so DoSomething(i) is not applicable.)

Comment: Add `class B { int i; ... }` and think again.

Comment: Why is this important? Why is `a.i` a nuisance?

Comment: a.i (and a.b, etc) is actually being used ~50 times throughout ClassB. But I can see why the example use appears trivial :)

Comment: 50 is still trivial, and there's no end to the maintenance problems from attempts to save a few keystrokes. Make it clearer, not shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property. Please note that `a.i` still needs to be `public` for both your example and mine.

```
public class ClassB
{
    private ClassA a;

    public ClassB(ClassA a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int i { get { return a.i; } }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```